# RSU do not receive sent messages in finish() function

Tags: omnet++, veins

I use OMNeT++-4.6, sumo-0.22.0 and Veins-4a2.

In my scenario, I modified the .rou.xml file in order that the path established by every node be from an RSU to another. Nodes create messages and they store them in their buffer according to the generated timer that I specified. After, nodes send messages to RSU (whether the source, destination or encountered RSU) according to the send timer.

My goal is that every node sends its messages when it leaves the simulation in order to empty its buffer and all messages created in the simulation will be send.

To do this scenario, I added some instructions in finish() function in the application layer of nodes: I send all packets stored in the buffer of the corresponding node like this:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < bufferSize ; i++) {

  msg = myBuffer.m[i];
  wsm->setWsmData(msg.c_str());
  sendMessage(wsm->getWsmData());   
}
```

The problem that sent messages in finish() function are not received by RSU, however when every node in my simulation leaves, it arrived at his destination which is an RSU.

- I need to understand please why these messages are not received by the RSU which is the destination?
- Is there another solution to send all stored messages before leaving the simulation?

Answer (score 2):

For sending a message using WLAN, a node commonly has to wait before it can access the channel. Until then, the messages are queued. If you enqueue the messages immediately before the node is destroyed, chances are very good the messages will never even start transmitting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. So, is there a way to make wait the node until it access the channel and send all its messages and after it leaves the simulation?

Comment: No such code is currently included with the framework. Writing it shouldn't be hard, but keep in mind that the network simulation will then no longer behave identical to the road traffic simulation. This might (or might not) be an issue, depending on what your simulation models.

Comment: At this moment in my simulation, it might not be an issue, I need to do this scenario. I need to know if I will write the code in the finish() function of the application layer of nodes? Have you an idea what can I change in the framework to do it please? How can I force nodes to wait until their sending packets will be send by receiving an ACK from RSU? Can I use sleep() function in finish() method to wait that packets access channel and will be send ?